# If my mortgage were to be foreclosed prior to completion of repayment, would I receive any cash value back for the payments I have made?

Tags: mortgage, default

First: This is hypothetical, more of a curiosity than something I need actual help with.

Lets say I had a 100k house, and over the past 10 years I'd paid down 50% of the value of the house -- That is to say ignoring interest, I own 50% and the bank owns 50%.

If I were to lose my job and get foreclosed, the bank probably wouldn't be interested in busting out a chainsaw to cut the house in half -- they'd take possession of 100% of the property.

Would the bank at that time (or any other) have to pay me back the 50% of the house I own? If not, how would this be handled?

Comment: You own the full house - but you also owe the bank the full value of the outstanding mortgage. The bank is able to use clauses in the mortgage to take possession of the house, if you fail certain tests, such as paying your mortgage on time. On taking possession of your house, they would be required to follow through on certain steps, as answered below - they can't simply take possession and then let manager live in it, for example. This distinction from you 'owning 50% of your house' is important, and leads to the result in the answer below.

Comment: In the case you cite, you would be lucky to get 10% due to fees and such.  Even if you had a "fire sale" you would likely net about 30%, which is why you would be best to sell before foreclosure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is "yes". The real-world answer is that what happens is:

(1) You miss a payment.
(2) They send you a bill the next month for two months' payment, plus late payment fees.
(3) You don't pay that bill.
(4) The bank sends increasingly serious letters to you asking for their money.
(5) At some point, the bank gives up on trying to work out a payment plan for you. 
(6) The bank starts foreclosure proceedings.
(7) The bank pays a bunch of court fees, hires a lawyer, and spends several months going through the foreclosure process. The bank continues charging you late fees throughout this time, and may have other fees as well.
(8) The court awards the bank title.
(9) The bank auctions the house, often at a significant discount.
(10) The bank takes the sale price, subtracts the loan, all the interest charges, the late fees, court fees, lawyer fees, etc., etc., and sends you a check for what's left over.

The larger your equity, the longer a bank will tend to spend in step (4), accruing more and more interest and late fees. It's not really in the bank's interest to foreclose just because you missed some payments; if there's enough equity that the bank can be sure of there being money left over after step (10), the optimal result is the bank continuing to charge you late fees until the equity is eaten up. Foreclosure is for when the bank has decided that they would rather have the house than you rack up more debt, i.e., there's no longer enough equity for them to be comfortable that they can recoup what they're owed if they wait any longer.  So in practice, there generally isn't much money, if any at all, left over after a foreclosure.

Answer (score 7):

Very basically, ignoring things like multiple liens, etc.  Generally, if you stop paying the bank can go through the foreclosure sale, if the bank sells the property for more than you owe the net, after sale expenses, proceeds are returned to you.

Comment: Though you would probably be better off selling the house yourself before the bank forecloses.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @quid’s answer, what you will get depends on many factors. As has been pointed out, a bank sale is likely to get a distressed, fire-sale price. A pre-forclosure sale is likely to get more. The bank has no incentive to maximize the sale price beyond their owed $50,000.

The price received at the sale will depend on whether comparable homes in the area have appreciated or depreciated since you bought the home. As well, it will depend on the state of repair and maintenance of your house. As in any real-estate sale, a neat, clean and recently painted home with curb-appeal will usually sell for more than a dirty, abandoned home with multiple repairs needed.

Although there are fees involved, for simplicity, let’s ignore them for a moment.

If the home you paid $100,000 for some years ago sells in foreclosure, or any other way, for that matter, for $75,000 and you have a $50,000 outstanding mortgage, you get $25,000.

Likewise, if it sells for $200,000 and you have a $50,000 outstanding mortgage, you get $150,000.

Finally, if, because of the loss of your job and the lack of available funds for maintenance and repair, the house sells for $48,000 and you have a $50,000 outstanding mortgage, you will *still* owe the bank $2,000 and they can be expected to pursue you for payment except for 12 non-recourse states in the USA.

Comment: **The last statement is true in some states and not in others. California, for example, is what is called a non-recourse state.** Generally speaking (get an attorney if this is really happening to you), the bank is _not_ entitled to go after you if there is still a deficiency after the foreclosure sale of the collateral (that is, the property). [Link](https://www.financialsamurai.com/non-recourse-states-walk-away-from-mortgage/) with list of the other non-recourse states.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Thanks for the information. I will edit my answer.

Comment: This is very useful to know. I had been under the impression that a foreclosure was the end of things and the bank would neither give nor take any further payment. The detail that you could get some excess or, more importantly, *still owe money* after a foreclosure seems very important to know.